# update cursor datetime if start date greater end date

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have 2 date fields in my feature class. If the start date is greater than the end date, I want to add 24 hours to the end date. I am getting a SetValue error.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("PolyFc")
for row in cursor:
    if row.getValue("START_DATE_VAL") > row.getValue("END_DATE_VAL"):
        row.setValue("END_DATE_VAL", row.getValue("END_DATE_VAL") + datetime.timedelta(hours=24))
    cursor.updateRow(row)
del cursor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably seeing an AttributeError exception? Use `setValue` (not `SetValue`).

Comment: Thanks! Oh man I can't believe I missed that. I updated my code above.